# Convergence of Metropolis Hastings with time varying proposal density

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, metropolis-hastings, stationarity

Suppose we have a Metropolis-Hastings sampler for a target distribution $f$, and we use a proposal density $Q_t$, that may depend on time $t$.  By construction, $f$ is still an invariant density of the chain, at every time step (*). However, the chain is not a Markov chain anymore, at least not a time homogeneous one. 
I'm pretty sure there exists some theory that ensures that the process  still converges to $f$, but can not find it in standard references. Where can such results be found?

* We assume that basic non degeneracy conditions hold, for instance both $f$ and all $Q_t$ are non-negative on the whole state space.

Comment: Are the $Q_t$s fixed beforehand or do they depend on the history of the chain?

Comment: I'm curious about both cases.  But the particular $Q_t$ 'sI have depend on the history.

Comment: (In case someone else stumbles upon this question.) In the setting when the proposal distribution is independent of the current state, Holden et al. (2009) in ["Adaptive independent Metropolis–Hastings"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-19/issue-1/Adaptive-independent-MetropolisHastings/10.1214/08-AAP545.full) provide strong results for convergence with very flexible adaptation options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is adaptive MCMC if your proposal distribution depends on the history of the chain, and is thus time dependent. There is a lot of theory about ergodicity of adaptive mcmc. There are essentially two main conditions:

1. Diminishing Adaptation: The adaptation on the proposal distribution should diminish as a function of $t$.
2. Containment: The time to stationarity remains bounded in probability. This is more of a technical condition and often difficult to check.

You can find a variety of references on this:

[These](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/research/miraw/days/montecarlo/abstracts/adaptivemiraw11_roberts.pdf) and [these](http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/Cambridge2010.pdf) set of slides go into some detail about adaptive MCMC.

[This](http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/adapt.pdf) is the paper that obtains the above conditions.

[Here](http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/adaptex.pdf) are some examples of adaptive MCMC.